# Number to array of digits with variable amount of padding zeroes

Tags: c#

I have a function that gets a `number` and an amount of `digits` and should return an array (or an ArrayList) of the digits in number that is exactly of size `digits`.

Sample Input 1: 12345, 6
Should Output: "012345"

Sample Input 2: 123456, 6
Should Output: "123456"

Sample Input 3: 1, 8
Sample Output: "00000001"

I am currently doing this

```
public int[] digitArrayFromNumber(int number, int digits){
    int[] result = number.ToString().PadLeft(digits, '0').ToArray().Select(
        ch => Convert.ToInt32(ch.ToString())
    ).ToArray();
    return result;
}
```

but that looks really ugly and it seems to me that there might be a better readable way to do this.

Comment: Ugly? It's a couple of lines of code tucked away in a function that you will rarely have to look at

Comment: @musefan Ugly code tends to have lots of bugs, which is why I am already reading this code for about the 5th time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use math:

```
int[] arr = new int[digits];
for (int i = 0; i < digits; i++)
{
    arr[digits - i - 1] = number % 10;
    number /= 10;
}
```

Use the modulus operator to retrieve the value of the last digit, and divide by ten to chop off the last digit.

Answer (score 3):

To get the numeric value of a digit character, you can simply subtract `'0'` from it.

```
int[] result = number.ToString("D" + digits).Select(i => i - '0').ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

You could format it a bit better and remove that first `ToArray()` (it isn't needed as a `string` is already a `IEnumerable<char>`), perhaps use `int.Parse` as it is shorter, as such,

```
public int[] digitArrayFromNumber(int number, int digits)
{
    return number.ToString()
        .PadLeft(digits, '0')
        .Select(c => int.Parse(c.ToString()))
        .ToArray();
}
```

However, @SLaks provides a simpler, shorter approach.